# Save HTML EDITOR CONTENT to Content-type .DOCX in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
 private void ConvertHTMLtoDOCX(string txtcode)
 {
     System.Text.StringBuilder strBody = new System.Text.StringBuilder("");

     strBody.Append("<html " + "xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " + "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'" + "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>" + "<head><title>Time</title>");

     //The setting specifies document's view after it is downloaded as Print
     //instead of the default Web Layout
     strBody.Append("<!--[if gte mso 9]>" + "<xml>" + "<w:WordDocument>" + "<w:View>Print</w:View>" + "<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>" + "</w:WordDocument>" + "</xml>" + "<![endif]-->");


     strBody.Append("<style>" + "<!-- /* Style Definitions */" + "@page Section1" + "   {size:8.5in 11.0in; " + "   margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in ; " + "   mso-header-margin:.5in; " + "   mso-footer-margin:.5in; mso-paper-source:0;}" + " div.Section1" + "   {page:Section1;}" + "-->" + "</style></head>");

     strBody.Append("<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>" + "<div class=Section1>" + Html_editor.Content + "</div></body></html>");

     //Force this content to be downloaded 
     //as a Word document with the name of your choice


     string FullFilePath = @"C:\Users\ravikant\Desktop\AR GitHub\07-05-2014\FinalTestARGithub\LetterTemplate\"+ txtcode+ ".docx"; 

     FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FullFilePath);
     if (file.Exists)
     {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "disExp", "<script>alert('File Already Exists');</script>");
     }
     else
     {
         Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
         Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename="+txtcode+".docx");
         Response.Write(strBody);
     }       
 }
```

Here is the code using the CONTENT-TYPE for .DOCX "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", the Content is corrupt while opening the file.

Comment: Check the file size of the file. Does it look like there is anything actualy saved into the file? Also I think your `file.Exists` check is mistaken. That will check if the file exists on the server, where as you are saving to the client. On your dev machine that is likley to be the same, but once you publish to a remote server you'll have issues.

Comment: the file size is 200kb its fine, it shows that the problem in the content.
Don't know why is this occurss, when i make the.doc or .xlsx this is make easy.

No error occurs while compile  the Code also, plz look into this matter.

Comment: As a first step, I'd remove the editor content from what you are saving. Put a basic `<p>Hello World</p>` in its place. If that works you know the issue is with the content from the editor. Check that content for html, xml, doctype, head and body tags. If it doens't work, there is something wrong with your saving procedure.

Comment: The file.exists are working fine, no issue from there.
Acutely i also create the file in different format, the file is created easily but for .DOCX i dont know.

Comment: Another hack that might help, I've done this with native word .docx, but not .docx generated in this manner, so it may or may not work. Make a copy of the saved file, change its extention from .docx to .zip. Try and open that. We are trying to find a  file `document.xml`,  which is normally in the "word" folder. Open that in a text editor an see if anything is jumping out as wrong or try putting it through an XML validator. VisualStudio should be good enough to show any malformating.

Comment: hmm u r rite while i open the file into the Word pad then it shows me the HTML content inside it, i got it why this is occurs. Thanks but can u tell me why its occurs even in DOC it doesn't happen

Comment: No Idea sorry, have you tired some basic html in place of the Editor content yet - see my 2nd comment? That will help narrow down where the issue lies.

Comment: Can u post ur Native word .docx method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to find out what is going on with the file.

I've done this with native word .docx, but not .docx generated in this manner, so it may or may not work.

1. Make a copy of the saved file, change its extention from .docx to .zip.
2. Try and open that. We are trying to find a file document.xml, which is normally in the "word" folder.
3. Open that in a text editor an see if anything is jumping out as wrong or try putting it through an XML validator. VisualStudio should be good enough to show any malformating.

Online XML Validator that might help: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

The following lines are also suspect:

```
strBody.Append("<!--[if gte mso 9]>" + "<xml>" + "<w:WordDocument>" + "<w:View>Print</w:View>" + "<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>" + "</w:WordDocument>" + "</xml>" + "<![endif]-->");
```

As I'm unsure how word will handle IE conditional comments. Comment out or remove this line and see what happens.

```
strBody.Append("<style>" + "<!-- /* Style Definitions */" + "@page Section1" + "   {size:8.5in 11.0in; " + "   margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in ; " + "   mso-header-margin:.5in; " + "   mso-footer-margin:.5in; mso-paper-source:0;}" + " div.Section1" + "   {page:Section1;}" + "-->" + "</style></head>");
```

Due to the nested comments. `<!-- /* */-->`. Perhaps try changing it to: `strBody.Append("</head>");` and see if that works.

Comment: ur method is fine, but still in trouble.
Sir, i know this type pf language are not allowed here, but i have very urgency , can u help me .

plz give some code in which html editor content are are saved to .docx format.

Comment: Sorry, but without more info I can't help. I've never saved from an HTML editor to a .docx file. What I've been trying to do here is narrow down the problem. With my answer and previous comments, I've been trying to work out if it is the text coming from the editor that is causing the problem or the method you are using to save it. More specifically the headers and such that you are wrapping the content in. Break the problem down. Try saving some hard coded HTML first. See if that works, if so, what you are wrapping the text in is OK and you need to look at what is coming out of the text...

Comment: ...editor. It may be containing tags that are making the XML invlaid. If saving with some hard coded text doesn't work then you have a problem with the additional XML tags that you are wrapping the content of the text editor with.

Comment: Ok sir, I put the HardText to my code, but the same prblm occurs. iam using the 2010 office is any problm occurs due to this.

' strBody.Append("<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>" + "<p>Hello World</p></body></html>"); '

Comment: Try putting the XML through the validator I linked to in my question. If it doesn't validate, it should tell you why, then try and fix those issues.